# Python - send uint8 and uint16 to socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to send some data with a python script to a java server. I use the socket module in python to send and recieve data.

When I send data, I need to specify a header with the datalength in it. The header is as following:

- a `uint8` for the version number
- a `uint8` for padding ('reserved')
- a `uint16` for the length of the data that is sent

That is a total of 32 bits.

I can use numpy to create an array with a certain data type, but the problem is sending this data through the socket. I use the following function to send data:

```
def send(socket, message):
    r = b''

    totalsent = 0
    # as long as not everything has been sent ...
    while totalsent < len(message):
        # send it ; sent = actual sent data
        sent = socket.send(message[totalsent:])

        r += message[totalsent:]

        # nothing sent? -> something wrong
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")

        # update total sent
        totalsent = totalsent + sent

    return r

message = (something_with_numpy(VERSION_NUMBER, PADDING, len(data)))
send(socket, message)
```

I keep getting TypeErrors with this function. These pop up at `len(message)`, `r += message[...]`, or some other place.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, or how to fix this so it does work?

---

UPDATE: here are some **exact** error traces. I have tried several different things, so these error traces might have become irrelevant.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 47, in <module>
    header += numpy.uint8(VERSION_NUMBER)
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S3') dtype('S3') dtype('S3')


header = numpy.array([VERSION_NUMBER * 255 + PADDING, len(greetData)], dtype=numpy.uint16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(header + greetData)
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S22') dtype('S22') dtype('S22')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 47, in <module>
    r = send(conn, numpy.uint8(VERSION_NUMBER))
  File "quick.py", line 13, in send
    while totalsent < len(message):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.uint8' has no len()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 47, in <module>
    r = send(conn, numpy.array([VERSION_NUMBER], dtype=numpy.uint8))
  File "quick.py", line 17, in send
    r += message[totalsent:]
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S3') dtype('S3') dtype('S3')
```

Comment: What is the **exact** error trace you obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `struct` module to format the header before sending the data.

```
import struct

def send_message(socket, message):
    length = len(message)
    version = 0  # TODO: Is this correct?
    reserved = 0  # TODO: Is this correct?
    header = struct.pack('!BBH', version, reserved, length)
    message = header + message  # So we can use the same loop w/ error checking
    while ...:
        socket.send(...)
```